# Is Python's raw_input() vulnerable to a buffer overflow?

Tags: python

Since CPython is implemented in C, when it reads a line from stdin, if the line exceeds whatever is the default size given to the string being read by the interpreter, would it cause a buffer overflow or does Python handle it?

Comment: FWIW, you can see the C source of `raw_input` [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/014060738f7f/Python/bltinmodule.c#l2299), although I guess you'd also need to read about the GNU [`readline`](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html) function too, since `raw_input` uses that if it's available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python dynamically sizes the string; it's not vulnerable to an overflow (though if the input is huge, it could raise a `MemoryError` when it can't expand the buffer further).

Python reads the input in chunks, and grows the buffer if it fills the buffer without finding a newline before reading another chunk.